# How to get TypeConverter of property

Tags: c#, typeconverter

I have this property:

```
    [DisplayName("Conexión")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(Converters.DevicesTypeConverter))]
    [Description("Conexión con el dispositivo a usar.")]
    [Required]
    public string Conexion { get; set; }
```

I need to get the type converter instance of it. I tried with :

```
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
        PropertyDescriptor property = properties.Find("Conexion", false);
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(property);
```

And even with:

```
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
        PropertyDescriptor property = properties.Find("Conexion", false);
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(property.PropertyType);
```

With that, I can only get converter of the property type, that is, the converter for string type, not the actual property converter, DevicesTypeConverter.

Any help please?

EDIT:

What I am trying to do is the following. I have 2 properties in the class that I need to set by mean of a property grid.

"Conexion" property is a list of values that depends on other property.

This dependency works well this way:

When the other property changes, and then I expand the "Conexion" property, GetStandardValuesSupported method on "Conexion" is called. Inside that method I use "context.Instance" to call a method on the object instance that retrieves the list this way:

```
    public List<object> GetDevicesList()
    {
        if (this.Driver == null)
            return null;

        var devices = this.Driver.GetList();

        if (devices == null)
            return null;

        return devices.Select(l => (object)l.Value).ToList();
    }
```

The returned list is stored in a private variable in the converter, so this perfectly show the list that depends on the other property.

So far so good. The problem occurs when the object already has value in its properties. Since the list of "Conexion" is exclusive, the property value of it, when I assign it to the property grid, appears empty.

This is obvious because the dependent list only get populated when GetStandardValuesSupported is called, and that happens only when I try to edit the property.

Now I need what I asked in the question. I need to call GetStandardValuesSupported explicitly in object constructor in order to force the dependent list to be loaded before the "Conexion" property is assigned. With that, I am sure the property will appear initialized since the list will have its value.

I think your solution should work but the GetConverter returns null. The problem is only reduced to call the GetStandardValuesSupported() of my custom type converter so I could also use Activator.CreateInstance but the problem is that the type of the converter is null and not the type of DevicesTypeConverter.

Comment: I am confused by what you are doing.  The property datya type is string, but you are trying to assign some other converter?

Comment: Yes. That converter shows a list of options. Each option is a string.

Answer (score 5):

You have to jump through several layers to get an instance of the `TypeConverter` specified in the `TypeConverterAttribute` ([LINQPad demo](http://share.linqpad.net/jm57ed.linq)):

```
//Get the type you are interested in.
var type = typeof(MyClass); 

//Get information about the property you are interested in on the type.
var prop = type.GetProperty("Conexion"); 

//Pull off the TypeConverterAttribute.
var attr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<TypeConverterAttribute>();

//The attribute only stores the name of the TypeConverter as a string.
var converterTypeName = attr.ConverterTypeName; 

// Get the actual Type of the TypeConverter from the string.
var converterType = Type.GetType(converterTypeName); 

//Create an instance of the TypeConverter.
var converter = (TypeConverter) Activator.CreateInstance(converterType);
```

You can use your existing method of getting the converter now that you have the type:

```
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(converterType);
```

Comment: I have thought about it. However, I think by creating such instance of TypeConverter, I will loose private variables of the converter, won't I? When I call the converter I will assign an internal variable. I need that variable to keep its value when I try to edit the property. Furthrrmore, I think if I use a static variable is an ugly solution.

Comment: If you require that kind of functionality, you should add it to your question.

Comment: I updated the answer to give a different method off obtaining the converter once you know its type.

Comment: I tried it but Type.GetType(converterTypeName); returns null. even when converterTypeName is "Configuracion.Converters.DevicesTypeConverter, Configuracion, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"

Comment: I have updated the question to tell you the whole scenario. I think your solution could work, however, Type.GetType returns null :-(

Answer (score 3):

You were close.  Once you have the PropertyDescriptor for the property you're interested in, use the Converter property to get the Converter.

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = properties.Find("Conexion", false);

propertyDescriptor.Converter // <- This is what you want
```

Comment: Agree--`PropertyDescriptor.Converter` will instantiate a type converter from the `TypeConverterAttribute` and falls back to calling `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter` on the property type if no attribute is present.